# why my c++ program uses significant memory when doing tcmalloc heap-checker or heap-profile

Tags: c++, memory, coroutine, tcmalloc

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

gcc version 4.8.5 20150623

gperftool 2.4-8.el7

1.my c++ program which links -ltcmalloc works fine without HEAPCHECKER or HEAPPROFILE. The memory it used stabilizes at 5M~10M.

2.if I run the program using heap-checker with **env HEAPCHECKER=NORMAL**,the memory increases about 50M per hour until OOM killer.

3.if I use heap-profile with **env HEAPPROFILE="./hp" HEAP_PROFILE_ALLOCATION_INTERVAL=100000000**, the memory increases about 100M per 40 minutes and also OOM is triggered.However, when I use pprof to analysis the heap file,it shows the total memory is only 0.1MB where I expect 100M.

I know heap-checker and heap-profile will cause extra memory use because they need to record some other information to trace memory allocation,but I don't think it is the reason for my case.

I use heap-checker and heap-profile with another small program,which works quite good.

The biggest difference between these two program is, the faulty program uses coroutine, by which i mean function swapcontext, getcontext and makecontext.

My questions are:

Q1.Why does the heap file opened by pprof show total memory is 0.1M when I set HEAP_PROFILE_ALLOCATION_INTERVAL=100000000?

Q2.Is it possible that heap-checker or heap-profile do not cooperate well with those coroutine functions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using stackful coroutines so you're making new stacks all the time. It may well be that the stacks are no longer fully destructed/freed when you're running the checkers so they in effect leak.